# How to upload image in multipart using python

Tags: python

I am using onfido library to upload a document on onfido
in multipart, but when I tried to upload the document dynamically
it is showing 500 internal server error in api. Below is the Python code which will upload the file.

```
        img_stream = self.request.get ('file')
       
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data'
        img = open(img_stream, "rb")
        
        self.response.out.write(img_stream)
        applicant_id = <applicant_id>  
        document_file = open(img_stream, "rb")
        document = api.Applicants.doccreate(applicant_id, document_file, "passport.png", 'Passport')
```

I have found this code from below url it is successfully uploaded the image
when we give static name of document in this line.

https://documentation.onfido.com/?python#upload-document

```
document_file = open("passport.png", "rb")
```

Please help me; where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works using 0.6 of [pyonfido](https://github.com/onfido/pyonfido):

```
from onfido import Api
api = Api(<token>)
applicant_id = <applicant_id>
document_file = open("document.jpg", "rb")
document = api.Documents.create(applicant_id, document_file, "document.jpg", "document")
```